# I have missing value (NA) using program Rstudio with Amelia but it doesn't work

Tags: r, missing-data

I use one variable and one country and it doesn't work and I use this code for RSTUDIO

```r
library(Amelia)
AmeliaView()
```

[image: Amelia result it doesn't work it said ERROR]

Comment: It seems to work. What do you expect. Which error you get?

Comment: Where's the problem? What data are you using? What (other) code are you using, and what have you tried? What is your expected result? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for great suggestions on how to improve questions to be reproducible and something that we can actually act on. As it stands, I don't know what you're doing with this.

Comment: What does your data look like? What is the error message. Would be great, if you could provide us with a minimal reproducible example like r2evans mentioned. Otherwise it is quite hard for us to help you.